# How to find and click on button contains img tag with text

Tags: c#, image, button, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find and click on button with text 'Log off' within  tags 
I tried with firebug xpath and css selectors it is working fine but when I am trying to customize and define not working

***What is working:***
**Firebug CSSSelector:** #RULE_KEY > div.layout.layout-noheader.layout-noheader-portal_header > div > div > div.content-item.content-layout.item-2.float-right.set-width-auto > div > div > div > div > div.content-item.content-field.item-4 > div > div > span > button

**Firebug Xpath:**//*[@id="RULE_KEY"]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGm9t.png)/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/span/button

***What is not working*** (my customized CSSselector or xpath)

**Xpath:** .//button[@class='pzhc']
**Css selector**: img[class='pzbtn-i']

in the above two trails it finding the first element with same class how can I define CSS selector to find with text 'Log off'

[button tag with text Log off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGm9t.png)

Comment: you cannot simply club to locators in selenium

Comment: I was able to resolve using XPath (//button[@type='button'])[2]). thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

With CSS selector we can not use text. But we can use text with xpath.
//*[text()='log off']

Comment: I was able to resolve using XPath (//button[@type='button'])[2]). thanks for the help.